# Aptana Studio Standalone JS autoformatting behaving differently from Eclipse Plugin version

Tags: eclipse, aptana, autoformatting

For some reason, when I format this block of dojo-fied javascript with Aptana's JS editor

```
var eventInput = new dijit.form.Select({
    name : 'event',
    options : [{
        label : 'Today',
        value : 'event-today',
        selected : true
    }, {
        label : 'Upcoming Birthday',
        value : 'event-birthday1'
    }, {
        label : 'Recent Birthday',
        value : 'event-birthday2'
    }, {
        label : 'Other',
        value : 'event-other'
    }]
}).placeAt('event-group');
```

Tabs are destroyed when it is autoformatted

```
var eventInput = new dijit.form.Select({
name : 'event',
options : [{
label : 'Today',
value : 'event-today',
selected : true
}, {
label : 'Upcoming Birthday',
value : 'event-birthday1'
}, {
label : 'Recent Birthday',
value : 'event-birthday2'
}, {
label : 'Other',
value : 'event-other'
}]
}).placeAt('event-group');
```

A similar block such as this

```
dojo.create('p', {
    id : 'subject-group'
}, 'form');
```

Formats correctly, preserving tabs.

The Eclipse Plugin version of Aptana does not do this and formats correctly. This is happening on a plain vanilla version of Aptana Studio 3, without any plugins or modifications. Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this was resolved for Aptana Studio 3.0.4.

See http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3022

You can grab the latest from the nightly builds at - http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/sgi/Changing+the+Update+Type

Cheers

Comment: Yep. You found it. I'll just switch to Eclipse IDE until 3.0.4 drops (tomorrow if their tracker is to be believed).

Comment: Not only I found it, I fixed it ;)